# I still can't update 12.04 LTS due to Broken packages, unmet dependancies....please see what I've tried

Tags: package-management

Here's what I'm doing to try & fix the brokern packages and here's the error messages that I'm receiving. What else can I do or run to get this 12.04 LTS to update and to also be able to use the software manager as well as Synaptic?
ten because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

```
     No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt
 ubuntu-sso-client-gtk
 software-center
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
rich@rich-Latitude-D620:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sso-client-gtk : Depends: python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
                         Depends: ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt : Depends: python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
                        Depends: ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

---

```
rich@rich-Latitude-D620:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-sso-client-qt
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-sso-client-qt
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/569 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-sso-client-gtk:
 ubuntu-sso-client-gtk depends on python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of python-ubuntu-sso-client on system is 3.0.2-0ubuntu3.
 ubuntu-sso-client-gtk depends on ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of ubuntu-sso-client on system is 3.0.2-0ubuntu3.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-sso-client-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-center:
 software-center depends on ubuntu-sso-client-gtk; however:
  Package ubuntu-sso-client-gtk is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing software-center (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-sso-client-qt:
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt depends on python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of python-ubuntu-sso-client on system is 3.0.2-0ubuntu3.
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt depends on ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of ubuntu-sso-client on system is 3.0.2-0ubuntu3.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-sso-client-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-sso-client-gtk
 software-center
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
rich@rich-Latitude-D620:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-sso-client-gtk : Depends: python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
                         Depends: ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt : Depends: python-ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
                        Depends: ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
rich@rich-Latitude-D620:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this will help you, but why not try removing the package that is broken?

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-sso-client-gtk
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-sso-client-gtk
```

Comment: I followed your instructions and although I think it did something different I'm still not sure what package my system is seeing or how to upgrade. here's the latest output 
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt depends on ubuntu-sso-client (= 3.0.2-0ubuntu1); however:
  Version of ubuntu-sso-client on system is 3.0.2-0ubuntu3.
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-sso-client-qt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-sso-client-gtk
 software-center
 ubuntu-sso-client-qt
rich@rich-Latitude-D620:~$ 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after upgrading from one LTS to another and trying to update flash. It complained about WINE (and then others) and refused to to do anything.

So I did this.

1. Open terminal if not already open.
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y [FIRST PACKAGE FROM LIST]` in my case this was `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y wine`
3. Type password
4. Wait for stuff to get taken care of.

In my case a whole massive uber-stack of packages started to install and update. Which explained a lot of minor issues I was having. So many "previously unselected" packages...

Assuming nothing is actually broken simply focusing on the things it is complaining about and updating them could well be the fix you need. Why this was not taken care of automatically is a whole other story and will be told another time.

YMMV.